# Asynchronously abort C# TPL Tasks

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

Is there a way to asynchronously abort C# TPL Tasks created with `Task.Factory.Create(() => {stuff});` ?  I have seen that there is a way of doing it using a `CancellationToken` but I like to avoid checking with `IsCancellationRequested`.

Comment: What's wrong with `IsCancellationRequested`? Cooperative cancellation is almost certainly what'll you want.

Comment: There is no way, and that is very deliberate.

Comment: It's a bad idea to yank the rug out from under another thread when you don't know what it might be doing with any shared state

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EDIT: Updated for .NET 4.5 and newer, details at the bottom of the post.

---

The `CancellationToken` is **the** thing you want to use. Checking the `IsCancellationRequested` may look like a pain, but it provides a clean way to handle the cancellation, as opposed to creating a thread, then aborting it and having to handle thread aborted exception in the whole code that is being run in parallel.

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var token = cts.Token;
var task = Task.Run(() =>
{
    // Do Job Step 1...
    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // Handle cancellation here, if necessary.

        // Thanks to @svick - this will set the Task status to Cancelled
        // by throwing OperationCanceledException inside it.
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }
    // Do Job Step 2...
    // ...
}, token);

// Later, to kill all the tasks and their children, simply:
cts.Cancel();
```

It may add some clutter to the delegate, but the cancellation itself is so easy that I never needed to use anything cruder than the cancellation token source. You haven't said why you'd like to avoid it, so unless there is some hard limitation, I'd stick with cancellation tokens.

---

As per @ipavlu's comment, for a simple use case like this, it's much better to use `Task.Run` instead of the original `Task.Factory.StartNew` to fire off the asynchronous work. They provide the same basic functionality, but `Task.Run` has safer defaults and better support for newer `async` features, while `Task.Factory.StartNew` can be used to specify advanced behavior. More info for example here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/10/24/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/

Comment: Instead of checking `IsCancellationRequested`, I think it's usually better to use `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`, so that the `Task` is marked as `Canceled`.

Comment: Make it use Default scheduler. This way it can cause deadlock, if the code here is executed in continuation which was running on UI context, then the task delegate will be running in UI context too instead on ThreadPool, the Default scheduler. It is good idea to set other options to prevent child attach etc... Task.Run implementation show best way to use StartNew...

Comment: @ipavlu: Updated. It's quite an old post, but it doesn't hurt to bring it to this decade.

Answer (score 7):

Cancellation can be difficult to implement, but that's mainly because cancellation, like parallel processing in general, is complicated.  You almost certainly don't want to allow aborting at arbitrary points in your code, as this creates almost as many new possible boundary cases to test as there are lines of your code in your asynchronously executed method.  This is the kind of nightmare scenario that leads to rare crashes in the wild that are almost impossible to reproduce.

Part of designing your asynchronous process is deciding where it's safe to cancel and how it should deal with cancellation.  This may also mean identifying blocking API calls you make (such as network I/O) and calling the appropriate methods to interrupt these blocking operations.  It takes a lot of up-front design effort to properly support cooperative cancellation, but, if the feature is required, the up-front investment will more than pay off in reduced headaches later.  It does mean, though, that you want to be conservative when budgeting for cancellation as a feature, since it's rarely as simple as it sounds.

Comment: Supporting cancellation is much simpler if library methods you're calling directly support it. So, for example, it might make sense to switch from `WebClient` to `HttpClient` for network IO.