# Stop a Task without ThrowIfCancellationRequested

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, cancellationtokensource

I have a task which i want to cancel.

The normal method for doing this is with `CancellationToken`.

```
this.task = new SpecialTask(() =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ushort.MaxValue; i++)
    {
        CancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}, this.CancelToken);
```

However, in real world things are never that simple.
Our async code cannot be looped and it looks like this:

```
this.task = new SpecialTask(() =>
{
    CancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    Operation1();

    CancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    Operation267(CancelToken);

    CancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    object232.Operation345();

    CancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    object99.Operation44(CancelToken);

    CancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    Operation5(CancelToken);

    ...

    CancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    Operation...n(CancelToken);

}, this.CancelToken);
```

I used random numbers for objects and method names to show that no loop can be created whatsoever.

What is most bothering is that I have to keep writing the same `CancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` over and over again.

And, as if that's not enough, I have to drag the `CancellationToken` all over my code just to be able to stop the long running operation - according to Microsoft - at the right time.

**Having said that, is there a way I can dispense of these repetitive calls which poison my code?**

We also know that, when using

```
try
{
    task.Wait(cancelToken);
}
catch(OperationCancelledException)
{
}
```

an `OperationCancelledException` is thrown and caught for the `Wait` method. However, the long operation executed by the task doesn't stop if there are no `CancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` checks from time to time.

**Is there any way possible to make the inside operation stop when the exception is caught for the wait?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asynchronously abort C# TPL Tasks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17321692/asynchronously-abort-c-sharp-tpl-tasks)

Comment: See [How do I cancel non-cancelable async operations?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/10/05/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations.aspx)  In short, you don't.  You either need to do this, or you can't cancel the task at all.  That said, you could do a few refactors to this code to avoid some of the repetition.

Comment: While I do understand the necessity of making sure the long running operation is stopped at the right time, I would have hoped that the framework had, at a lower level, some inbuilt mechanism for cancelling nicely. I will look into the link you provided as soon as possible, though. Thanks!

Comment: @Paul There is no way for the system to know when a good or bad time to stop is; you need to tell it.

Answer (score 2):

You can refactor your code into a loop to avoid the repetitive cancellation between each line:

```
var actions = new List<Action>()
{
    ()=>Operation1(),
    ()=>Operation267(CancelToken),
    ()=>object232.Operation345(),
    //...
};

foreach (var action in actions)
{
    action();
    CancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
}
```

Comment: This would require me to imagine much finer grain for my code separation into methods. Instead of having 3 good solid methods, I am almost forced to split into much smaller methods only so that the cancellation is caught soon enough.

Elliminating a code nuissance from one place and adding another one somewhere else just won't do

Comment: @Paul You can still pass the cancellation token into the methods and do the same thing in those, to still allow refactoring code into methods.